# How to use smb to mount a directory of an ubuntu server on an ubuntu guest machine?

Tags: 20.04, smb

I have setup a shared samba folder on an ubuntu 20.04 server. The below code is in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file:

```
[tidy-mine]
path = /media/tidy/mine
valid users = tidy
read only = no
E45: 'readonly'
```

I want to mount the above shared folder on the `/home/guest/f_folder` directory of a guest machine that runs ubuntu 20.04. The local ip address of the server is `192.168.1.10`. What commands should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be via the Terminal:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o uid=tidy,username=tidy,password=superSecretPassword!123 //192.168.1.10/tidy-mine /home/guest/f_folder
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `superSecretPassword!123` with the actual password you have set.</sup>

You will need to create the `f_folder` directory first, otherwise there will be no place for the share to be mounted to.

Comment: I received the error `mount: /media/tidy/f_folder: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.`

Comment: This command worked: `sudo mount -t cifs -o     username=tidy,password=My_Password_is_something_secrect  //192.168.1.11/tidy-mine  /home/digital/tidy `. I have two questions, how can I unmount when I decide to? Also, how can I give the password as a hidden prompt instead of giving the password in plain text?

Comment: I found the answers. For un-mounting I use `sudo umount /home/digital/tidy`. For prompting the password I use `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=tidy   //192.168.1.11/tidy-mine  /media/tidy/f_folder/
`

Answer (score 4):

Install `cifs` with

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Create the mountpoint.

```
sudo mkdir /home/guest/f_folder
```

and mount it ...

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.10//media/tidy/mine /home/guest/f_folder
```

- Please use dedicated mount points for both directories.

  - `/media` is for removable storage. Not the best place to set up a samba mount and it will break your setup when you remove the medium.
  - use /home/guest/f_folder`if you really want to but I would advice against it. It is so easy to mess up when you use` /home`.

Comment: I received the error `Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)`